# Output the Words Position in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file to analysis and the requirement is to output the dictionary, and the key is the word,
value is the word position(Some words appear in the text several times, so the word has more than one position as the value in the dictionary ). Such as anywhere:`[1,4,6,8,10]`. But my output only appears one
position of the word, such as anywhere:`[1]`. I'm really confused here, and here is my code and output. 
Also, I'm restricted by only using build-in functions, I cannot import any others.

```
file_name = input('Enter the file name: ')
words_data = open(file_name, 'r')
words_list = []
new_word_list = []
word_index= []
dictionary = {}
for line in words_data:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        words_list.append(word.lower())
for word_p in words_list:
    word_np = word_p.strip('?.,;:!-')
    new_word_list.append(word_np)
    if word_np in new_word_list:
        word_index.append(new_word_list.index(word_np))

dictionary = {}

for final_word in new_word_list:
    word_position = dictionary.get(final_word,None)
    if word_position == None:
            dictionary[final_word] = new_word_list.index(final_word)

print(dictionary)
```

```
#Outputs#
Enter the file name: greenEggsham.txt
{'rain': 420, 'car': 194, 'thank': 778, 'try': 635, 'eggs': 20, 'could': 190, 'or': 42, 'them': 27, 'there': 43, 'fox': 143, 'the': 393, 'see': 216, 'good': 719, 'be': 239, 'train': 301, 'boat': 518, 'would': 37, 'that': 6, 'let': 237, 'so': 632, 'do': 11, 'i': 0, 'with': 83, 'will': 215, 'like': 13, 'ham': 22, 'you': 17, 'green': 19, 'am': 1, 'are': 201, 'goat': 503, 'they': 200, 'here': 41, 'me': 238, 'and': 21, 'eat': 132, 'in': 76, 'house': 78, 'if': 650, 'on': 312, 'say': 391, 'sam-i-am': 7, 'dark': 394, 'not': 12, 'anywhere': 57, 'box': 136, 'sam': 2, 'may': 211, 'a': 77, 'spam': 384, 'tree': 223, 'mouse': 85}
```

Comment: In your dictionary, maintain values as a list(append your positions) instead of an integer.

Comment: Did the answer solve your query? If yes, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the dictionary value everytime you access the key. As shaik mentioned, use a list as a dictionary value and append to the list everytime.

Eg:

```
for final_word in new_word_list:
    word_position = dictionary.get(final_word,None)
    if word_position == None:
            if final_word in dictionary:
                dictionary[final_word].append(new_word_list.index(final_word))
            else:
                dictionary[final_word] = [new_word_list.index(final_word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with `enumarate` :

```
for final_word in new_word_list:
    word_position = dictionary.get(final_word,None)
    if word_position == None:
        dictionary[final_word] = [index for index, value in enumerate(new_word_list) if value==final_word]
```